# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{1 + 2e^{-s} +e^{-2s}}$

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I need to find a function $g(t)$ such that $h(t)*g(t)=\delta(t)$,
where
$$
h(t) = \delta(t) + 2\delta(t-1) + \delta(t-2) \;.
$$
I have found
$$
H(s) = 1 + 2\mathrm{e}^{-s} + \mathrm{e}^{-2s}
$$
and
$$
H(s)G(s)=1
$$
and thus
$$
G(s) = \dfrac{1}{1 + 2e^{-s} + \mathrm{e}^{-2s}} \;,
$$
but I am unsure how to find the inverse Laplace transform of $G(s)$. I have reason to believe that it may involve an infinite series, but I can't find any examples similar to this.

How can I find $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{1 + 2e^{-s} + \mathrm{e}^{-2s}}\right\}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize how similar the asterisk looks to the convolution symbol in Tex.

Comment: I don't understand the edits made here: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2325824/revisions

Comment: The Laplace transform of $\delta(t-1)$ is $e^{-s}$ and not $2^{-s}$. Do you agree? BTW if you are new here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I agree. However, the laplace transform of $2\delta(t-1)$ is $2e^{-s}$, right? I do see that I was missing an "e" in one of those.

Comment: Sorry. My fault.

Comment: I was starting to worry I was really going crazy ;) This all looks right to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you would like to  find a function $g(t)$ such that $h(s)*g(s)=\delta(t)$ (where $*$ means convolution),
where $h(t) = \delta(t) + 2\delta(t-1) + \delta(t-2)$.

After taking the Laplace Transform of both parts we get $H\cdot G=\mathcal{L}\{\delta\}=1$  (where $\cdot$ means multiplication) .
Hence, we need to compute the  inverse Laplace transform of
$$G(s)=\frac{1}{H(s)}=\frac{1}{1 + 2e^{-s} + e^{-2s}}=\frac{1}{(1 + e^{-s})^2}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(-1)^ne^{-ns}.$$
By recalling that
$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(e^{-ns})=\delta(t-n)$,
we obtain
$$g(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(-1)^n\delta(t-n).
$$

Comment: Thank you. I think the big part I'm missing, though, is that last step where the fraction becomes a summation. How is that expanded?

Comment: @Matt Take the derivative of $1/(1-y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^n$, let $x=-y$ and shift the index.

Comment: @Matt Is my guessing about your question correct? That is that you would like to  find a function $g(t)$ such that the convolution of $h(s)$ and $g(s)$ is $1$. In case could you please edit your question?

Comment: Apologies. I have corrected the confusing symbols in my question. I am looking to find g(t) to "undo" h(t) in the signal path.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @Anonymous is it better now?

Comment: alright, I understand the transition to the summation now. Last question: Since I'm looking for $H(s)G(s)=1$, why do you take $\mathcal{L}\{1\}$ ?  I think this should just end up being $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n-1)(-1)^ne^{-sn}$ which is a series of impulses?

Comment: @Matt If you need $h(t)*g(t)=1$ (where $*$ means convolution) then after taking the Laplace Transform of both parts we get $H\cdot G=\mathcal{L}\{1\}$  (where $\cdot$ means multiplication) . Do you agree?

Comment: I think my brain is being very fuzzy today. I suppose that bit at the very top should actually be $g(t)*h(t)=\delta(t)$, so that, for example, $x(t)=g(t)*h(t)*x(t)$.  I am terribly sorry for all the confusion. My big issue (outside of all of my Tex typos) was getting from the $G(s)$ fraction to the summation.

Comment: @Matt I edited my answer. Is everything OK now?

Comment: yes, thank you! You deserve gold stars all around.